# VBA Allow to copy only visible cells in a protect sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a protected sheet with the options below and this sheet contains some hidden rows / columns.

```
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws.Name).EnableOutlining = True
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws.Name).Protect password, _
            AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
            AllowFormattingRows:=True, _
            userInterfaceOnly:=True, _
            contents:=True, _
            AllowFormattingCells:=True
```

And I use this code to block sheets but I want to allow users to also copy only visible cells (using alt +; for example).

I saw the Microsoft website with the documentation (already posted by @Mech), but I tested the options and none worked except the option Contents:= False, but this option set to False allows the user to copy only visible cells edit the contents of the cells (which I don't want to happen).

Does anyone know any other way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.protect

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should do what you are looking for based on unprotecting the cells for copying purposes.

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="password"
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="password", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
```

src: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/copy-only-visible-cells-on-protected-sheet-book.412461/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got to see the link but would there be a solution without the need to put a button? Only using alt +; to select the visible cells and then ctrl + c. I would mark your answer as helpful, but I don't have 15 reputation points yet :(

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: This post says that unfortunately it is not possible. Unfortunately. Thanks for the help https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/select-visible-cells-button-not-working-anymore.330130/